# Add a path in $PATH globally for every user

Tags: path, aix

Do we have anyway to add a path globally so that each user gets it in $PATH. I want to add path of ANT so that each user doesn't need to add it in his $PATH variable.

Comment: If you intend users to run a particular shell, say bash, then you could add the `export` line in `/etc/bashrc` as it will be read systemwide.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Global paths should be set in `/etc/profile` or `/etc/environment`, just add this line to `/etc/profile`:

```
PATH="$PATH:/path/to/ANT/bin"
```

Comment: For ksh shell it was not working..after switching to bash shell it is working. Above changes are specific to bash shell ?

Comment: @feelgoodandprogramming no, it should also work for `ksh`, but only if `ksh` is your login shell. The `/etc/profile` file is only read by login shells, so if you log in with `ksh`, then it will be read and any variables set there will be inherited by any other shells you launch. The details can get quite complicated though, I suggest you open a new question, tell us what operating system you use, how you log in, what your `$SHELL` is and other details and then we can examine why it didn't work for you.

Answer (score 27):

Many Linux distributions support the Linux Standard Base `/etc/profile.d` directory where configurations such as additional paths directives can go without touching the stock system files. The file name just needs an .sh extension.

For example

```
cat >> /etc/profile.d/some_name.sh << \EOF
  PATH=$PATH:/path/to/ANT/bin
EOF
```

Comment: The OP tagged it [AIX], though...

Comment: The [LSB/*Linux Standard Base* Specification](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/lsb.shtml) indeed specifies the `/etc/profile.d` directory: ...

Comment: ... [*LSB 5.0 Core Specification, Generic Part. Chapter 18. File System Hierarchy. 18.2. `/etc`: Host-specific system configuration*](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/etc.html): "*A directory containing shell scripts. [...] The **sh** utility shall read and execute commands in its current execution environment from all the shell scripts in this directory that have the suffix `.sh` when invoked as an interactive login shell, or if the `-l` [...] is specified [...].*" ...

Comment: ... [*LSB 5.0 Core Specification, Generic Part. Chapter 17. Commands and Utilities. 17.2. Command Behavior: **sh***](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/sh.html): "*[An interactive login / `-l `shell [...] shall] first read and execute commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists, and then from a file called `~/.profile`, if such a file exists. **Note:** [**sh** shall also read and execute scripts in the directory `/etc/profile.d`]. Such scripts are read and executed as a part of reading and executing `/etc/profile`.*"

Answer (score -1):

Edit /etc/profile and update the Path manipulation section. Centos does not include the /usr/local/bin in the path.

```
# Path manipulation
if [ "$EUID" = "0" ]; then
    pathmunge /usr/sbin
    pathmunge /usr/local/sbin
    pathmunge /usr/local/bin
else
    pathmunge /usr/local/bin after
    pathmunge /usr/local/sbin after
    pathmunge /usr/sbin after
fi
```

Comment: It looks like your code assumes `bash` is being used. Also, notice the [tag:aix] tag on the question. This user is not using CentOS.