# How do I install WP-CLI for all users on centOS 7

Tags: centos, command-line, wordpress

I've followed the instructions provided on the [wp-cli.org site](http://wp-cli.org/) but I can't seem to get the `wp` command to run for all users.

I copied the file to `/usr/local/bin` and renamed it to `wp` per the instructions. And when I'm logged in as root I can run wp from anywhere and it works (although it gives me the "are you sure you want to run this as root?" warning).

I was under the impression that moving an executable to `/usr/local/bin` would make that executable available to all users. However, when I switch to another user, I get a "command not found" error.

How can I install wp-cli for all users? I want to make sure every user with SSH access can run wp-cli.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to add `/usr/local/bin` to the `PATH` globally.

Comment: This is actually in the global user PATH. When I login as a non-root user and run echo $PATH this is what I get:

```/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/cpanel/composer/bin:/home/iansvoboda/.local/bin:/home/iansvoboda/bin```

The problem is that the binary ```wp``` isn't present in ```/usr/local/bin``` for non-root users. 

Also, I'm running WHM, so I suppose there could be some security restriction or something on 3rd party binaries?

Comment: What do you get if you run `/usr/local/bin/wp`?

Comment: ```-bash: /usr/local/bin/wp: No such file or directory```

This is what I would expect, since as I said the binary doesn't appear to be present in that directory for a non-root user. I have no idea why though.

Comment: I would expect `/usr/local/bin/` to be the same for everybody.  But that command works for you as `root`?

Comment: Yes it does. The contents of that directory as root do not much the contents of non-root users. I'm thinking that perhaps the other binaries in that directory are hidden from non-root users by default or something. But I'm not having much luck turning up a solution yet

Comment: Does www-data own the file? Any reason to not have users use sudo to use wp-cli? That would still meet your requirement for SSH users to access it.

Comment: File owner is root. As far as sudo goes, I guess I thought that was only something a root user would run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I determined that the issue was related to cageFS.

**Solution**

If the server environment is using CloudLinux with cageFS enabled, cageFS definitions must be updated to allow the wp command to be accessible to non-root users

I found these instructions here to do this: https://docs.redy.host/knowledge-base/install-wp-cli-cpanel-cagefs/

Answer (score 0):

Generic solution is to [install WP-CLI](https://www.sitepoint.com/wp-cli/) as the root user, typically putting it in `/usr/local/bin`:

#### Step 1

`curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar`

#### Step 2

`chmod +x wp-cli.phar`

#### Step 3

`sudo mv wp-cli.phar /usr/local/bin/wp`

Now add `/usr/local/bin` to the $PATH of each user which can either be done locally for each user by adding `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin` into the `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` or, even cooler, but adding that path [globally](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/265100) from the root user by putting the PATH export in a bash script within `/etc/profile.d/`. For example:

#### Step 4

```
# /etc/profile.d/add_user_local_bin.sh
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

Now all the users can use wp-cli commands. Cool.